# SmartSVN Repository moved permanently

Tags: apache, svn, smartsvn

I recently set up an svn repo with authentication.

Our PC users are using tortoise SVN and are able to checkout, commit, etc.

Our Mac OS users are using SmartSVN and when trying to checkout they get the following error:

```
Repository moved permanently; please relocate OPTIONS
request failed on'/'
```

I ran into this issue when setting it up initially with tortoisesvn and the solution was making sure that that svn repo wasn't a child of the www directory. So I placed it in the home directory

The home directory looks like the following:

```
/public_html
/repos
/www
```

The vhost conf file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_dav_svn.c>
 <Location /repos/>
  DAV svn
  SVNParentPath /data/svn/repos/
  SVNListParentPath On
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "SVN Repository"
  AuthUserFile /data/svn/.htpasswds/.svn.htpasswd
  AuthzSVNAccessFile /data/svn/.htpasswds/.svn.authz
  Require valid-user
 </Location>
</IfModule>
```

Both PC and Mac users are able to view the repositories with the proper authentication in a browser. The only issue is when trying to checkout when using SmartSVN on MacOS.

There aren't any errors in the log that I can see that relate.

**Edit: Clarification**
All users are checking out the repos with a url format like:

```
http://svn.myserver.com/repos/REPONAME
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Originally our svn was using a single repository and we changed it to use a collection of repositories. We were still using the same subdomain "svn.server.com" with the main difference that our collection is now svn.server.com/repos/

SmartSVN stored the old url "svn.server.com" and seemed to ignore the new supplied url during checkout (svn.server.com/repos/TEST)

The solution is simple.

```
SmartSVN > Preferences > Authentication
```

Delete the old record and then try to check out again.

Answer (score 0):

> Both PC and Mac users are able to view the repositories with the proper authentication in a browser

Browser in your case is not the best testing-tool. CLI-based SVN-client will give more details about problem

In your case Mac-users (I *suppose*) tried to read repository root, not repository (it's possible in browser **only** with `SVNListParentPath On` in config, as you have). Any SVN client on any OS (for current stable 1.7) **can not read SVNParentPath** (promised to be changed in 1.8) and **must** to use

`svn ls SERVER/repos/REPONAME` as minimal root-level for *single* repository

Comment: Sorry; I knew I forgot to mention something in my post. Both Mac and PC users are checking out the repos in the manner that you mentioned. That is; SERVER/repos/REPONAME. I'll add that to my post.

Comment: It appears that I can't use any svn commands with the http protocol. Unrecognized URL scheme. I guess I need install Neon.

Comment: @Veo - good catch. Test it with `svn --version` and get active RA-layers

Comment: ra_svn and ra_local. I'd like to note that I JUST now solved the main issue of the MacOS users not being able to checkout. But if there's an easy way to get neon or the http protocol installed without having to reinstall svn I'm interested.